# ASP.net - The virtual path '/Master.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, virtual-path

I have an asp.net master page located in the root directory of my site. I have a page in the directory "/myfolder" from the master page:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="myproject.TimelapseDefault" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 <p>
```

The files look like:

/Master.master
/myfolder/default.aspx

Why do I get this error, when I upload it to my (non dedicated godaddy iis 7) server, but it works on localhost?:
 Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The file '/timelapserpro/Master.master' does not exist.

Source Error:

Line 1:  `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="myproject.TimelapseDefault" %>`

Line 2:      `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">`
Line 3:      `<p>`

All pages are in the same solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change `MasterPageFile="../Master.master"` to `MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"`

Also check if you create virtual folder on your iis 7 properly. Check if path to your app is correct. You have to have such folder structure in your IIS

```
->YourAppName (the root of your app contains your root files)
  ->myfolder (contains your myfolder content)
```

Comment: If I do, i get "The file '/myfolder/Master.master' does not exist.", but on the local server it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I had accidentally set the directory as an application root.

Comment: how did you changes that?

Comment: @wordpressm see on `top of` the your `.aspx` page it should contain `MasterPageFile="path.to.your.masterpage.file"`. Change it there. And take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX

Answer (score 4):

Your remote server doesn't have the folder set up as a web application, so when you refer to it with "~", it is looking in the root of the application which happens to be the server root.

BUT, on your local machine, '/timelapserpro/`is a full application so ~/ refers to '/timelapserpro`, not '/'.

You need to either demote your application on the local server so it isn't it's own app anymore, or to promote the destination server folder to be an application to get the two to sync up.