# Server Error in '/' Application Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost

Problem is when I run the project from visual studio it works fine but when I run the applicaiton from localhost I get the following error.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: The virtual path '/assets/masters/homepage.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/assets/masters/homepage.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Extra_dNet_Code" Runat="Server">

Source File: /WebSite4/default.aspx    Line: 1
```

Though, there is no error in visual studio, it shows several warnings.

This is where the error give in following file  /assets/masters/homepage.master

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/assets/masters/homepage.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271205/asp-net-the-virtual-path-master-master-maps-to-another-application-which-i

Comment: You need to correct this page. /assets/masters/homepage.master . Make it relative

Comment: I tied following. ~/, ../, ./ but didnt work.

Comment: It sounds like you have configured the sub directory as an application in your local IIS.  Fix that, and you should be good.

Comment: yes I have created a sub directory under wwwroot folder and put the site. How to fix that?

Comment: @jadarnel27, Can you explain your comment please?

Comment: Sorry for being unlcear.  It sounds like you have "WebSite4" configured as an application within IIS.  Correct?  However, it sounds like you also may have accidentally configured one of the folders under it as an application.  If that's the case, you need to change it back so that it's just a folder, and not an application.  Does that make sense?

Comment: 'Website4' is under 'Default Web site'. But I haven't conveted a folder in Website4 to application